# compare strings and if match dynamically assign a css style rule in spring and jsp

Tags: css, jsp, spring-mvc

I have two set of data with string and date fields ex: first name and DOB with a matchflag for each field, I need to compare these set of values and if there is a match, apply css style rule to one set of the data dynamically. I need to do in spring controller and display in jsp page. I am new to spring, any idea would be great.

Thanks in advance,
Sailaja.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is too vague. But I will try to answer below; You can have a model attribute to hold the matching decision, so it can be used in jsp.

I am assuming you have a Data object as below:

```
class Data{
    String fName;
    Date dob;
}
```

And your controller handler method code may have a model attribute to hold 'matched' flag

```
public String handlerMethod(Model model) {
    Data obj1;
    Data obj2;

    boolean   matched = SomeUtil.compare(obj2, obj2);
    model.addAttribute("cssClass"  , matched?"matched":"unmatched");

    return "yourjsp";
}
```

Your jsp can have field with class as below:

```
<div class="${cssClass}">
    Fields here..
</div>
```

Your css file can have the style defined

```
.matched {
    ...
}
.unmatched {
    ...
}
```

See if it helps.

Comment: Can I do this using javascript?

Comment: setting classname from javascript: `document.getElementById("<<Element id>>").className = "<<class name>>"`;

Comment: I am doing using jquery $('#id').addClass('classname');